# Is OPs method of trying to solve a problem the way we should answer it?

Tags: discussion

I just had a discussion with a member regarding this.

OP asked how do I solve "this" and used a way that is not generally used as his attempt.
I answered the question with what is the "mainstream" way of dealing with the problem.

The member I had the discussion expresses he should flag my answer since it does not answer the question in the same way as OP asks for.

Is the way OP asks a question the way we should answer them or should we answer with a better/best method given the result is still the "same"?

Thread: [PHP initialize variable with loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47626224/php-initialize-variable-with-loop)

Comment: This has been asked many times before ^^^^^^^. Also see: [Google Search: site:https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ "xy problem"](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2F+"xy+problem")

Comment: I tried to find a duplicate but I'm not very good friend with the search here. Usually I find it easier to find duplicates on Google, but I was unlucky there too this time. Thanks for finding it.

Comment: Same for me, I usually find Google much easier and more effective to use, but please click on my search link above to see how to get the best of both worlds!

Comment: I'm not sure I dare. Best of two world's... Sounds scary.

Comment: What's scarier to me is that there are Mjolnir-wielding gold-badge users on meta (@Cerbrus). I didn't know that you could get gold-badges on this site of stack exchange.

Comment: That's it! I'm never taking off my tin foil hat now.

Comment: It's rather simplistic; you answer the question asked. If that doesn't happen to be the question that the OP wanted to ask... then many things went wrong in between. A) the OP did not ask what he wanted to know and B) the question was probably answered too hastily without asking for further details. A) is really not our problem if the question was still correct and answerable. They'll just have to ask another question and this time think about it.